# Is there an app / library allowing me to record HTML5 WebRTC and edit it online in the same place?

Tags: video, html, chrome, video-editing, webcam

I managed to find the following demo:
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

I can record stream from my webcam and replay it later. I can also right click, save to computer and add `.webm` extension to play in a browser.

What I'm looking for is an **video editor** (can be basic) on top of that:

- trimming (removing unwanted fragments)
- annotations (adding shapes such as arrows to the screen)

### Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does your requirement have to be able to edit WebRTC before uploading?

My app [StepUp.io](http://www.stepup.io) lets you do trimming and basic annotation against any YouTube videos. Unless you want to trim long video into small bites, you could just upload and edit it once uploaded.

If you persuade me otherwise, I may add the feature request into my product backlog :-)